# set variable time to SchTasks

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, python-datetime, windows-task-scheduler

This is what i have done so far

```
import subprocess
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now_plus_10 = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds = 10)
path=r"path_to_file"
subprocess.call(['SchTasks', '/Create','/SC', 'ONCE','/TN', 'test1','/TR', path,'/ST', now_plus_10])
subprocess.call(['SchTasks', '/Create','/SC', 'ONCE','/TN', 'test2','/TR', path,'/ST', now_plus_10])
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.datetime' is not iterable
```

If I use the time directly like this,the task is scheduled successfully:

```
time="09:06"
subprocess.call(['SchTasks', '/Create','/SC', 'ONCE','/TN', 'test3','/TR', path,'/ST', time])
```

If there is any other way to do this,it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: okay `now_plus_10` was getting date as well & time too in miliseconds
if i remove that ,then maybe it will run!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
```

I believe `arg` is of type `datetime.datetime` and you are using `in` operator on it. `in` operator works only on objects which can be iterated, for example, lists, dicts, sets etc. So, what you need to do is, convert `arg` to string using `strftime`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother you guys. I got the answer now

```
import subprocess
import time

currenttime = time.time()
new= time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(currenttime + 0.6* 60))
path=r"path_to_file"
subprocess.call(['SchTasks', '/Create','/SC', 'ONCE','/TN', 'test1','/TR', path,'/ST', new])
subprocess.call(['SchTasks', '/Create','/SC', 'ONCE','/TN', 'test2','/TR', path,'/ST', new])
```

Thanks for helping anyways!